# Scapy slow performance when editing big pcap in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, scapy

I am trying to fix packet capture after hard slicing where frame length (wirelen) is incorrect and messes up Wireshark analysis.

I managed to do it using Scapy, but problem is it takes a lot of time to do it. For 236000 packets it takes up to 4 minutes, when Tracewrangler app on windows takes 9 seconds on same file.

Am I doing something wrong or it is just a way it is?

scapy==2.4.3, RHEL7.8, Python 3.6.8

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime

time_start = datetime.now()

packets = PcapReader('original_big_file.pcap')
new_cap = PcapWriter("new_big_file.pcap", append=True)

for packet in packets:
    len_delta = packet[IP].len - len(packet[TCP].payload) - 40
    new_wirelen = packet[Ether].wirelen + len_delta
    packet[Ether].wirelen = new_wirelen
    new_cap.write(packet)

time_delta = datetime.now() - time_start
print(time_delta)
```